# cmake : Set environment variables from a script

Tags: linux, cmake, environment-variables, cross-compiling, build-system

I have a script that sets all variables needed for the cross-compilation. Here is just part of it :

```
export CONFIG_SITE=~/workspace/eldk-5.4/powerpc/site-config-powerpc-linux
export CC="powerpc-linux-gcc  -m32 -mhard-float --sysroot=~/workspace/eldk-5.4/powerpc/sysroots/powerpc-linux"
export CXX="powerpc-linux-g++  -m32 -mhard-float --sysroot=~/workspace/eldk-5.4/powerpc/sysroots/powerpc-linux"
export CPP="powerpc-linux-gcc -E  -m32 -mhard-float --sysroot=~/workspace/eldk-5.4/powerpc/sysroots/powerpc-linux"
export AS="powerpc-linux-as "
export LD="powerpc-linux-ld  --sysroot=~/workspace/eldk-5.4/powerpc/sysroots/powerpc-linux"
export GDB=powerpc-linux-gdb
```

If I do `source environment-setup-powerpc-linux`, all environment variables are imported into the current shell session, and I can compile my example.

Is it possible to import these variables in cmake? If yes, how?

---

A bit more details :

1. I am using [ELDK v 5.4](http://www.denx.de/wiki/ELDK-5), and it's install script generates a script which sets all environment variables
2. I found [this tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CmakeEldk), which explains how to manually set for cross-compilation, but not how to use the script, which sets everything
3. if I call the script before setting cmake, all works fine, and I can cross-compile, but I'd like that cmake calls the script

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Reading through the [cmake quick start](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Eadanner/tips/cmake.php), you can specify variable on a command line:

```
cmake -DVARIABLE1=value1 -DVARIABLE2=value2 ...
```

Otherwise, `set` command in the cmake script is probably what you want, see the [reference manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-environment-variable). To set the **environment variable** PATH, do:

```
set(ENV{PATH} "/home/martink")
```

To set normal variable, do:

```
set(variable "value")
```

Not sure which ones you have to set, probably the environment ones.

That said, *setting environment variable prior to calling cmake* is often the easiest solution to solve the problem. If you want a cross-platform way to do this that doesn't depend on the syntax of a specific shell to set environment variables, there is the [`cmake -E env`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool:%7E:text=no%20new%20line.-,env,-%5B%2D%2Dunset%3DNAME%20...%5D) command.

Comment: set(ENV{PATH} "/home/martink") does this work for anyone? Its not working in mine

Comment: @PriteshAcharya There is a typo, type set($ENV{PATH} "/home/martink")

Comment: @JeanDavy I don't think that's a typo - set($ENV{PATH} "/home/martink") will put the current value of PATH where you specified $ENV{PATH} as the variable name, and so it won't set what you think you're setting. I just did this myself by accident!    A more usual setting of path would be set(ENV{PATH} "/home/martink:$ENV{PATH}") and that's where the '$' would be necessary.

Comment: excuse me, but in what file should I add that set(...) command? I see some *.cmake files and CMakeFiles directory and a Makefile from where I build.(the build directory)

Comment: @PriteshAcharya yes, for me it works (CMake v3.7). (I am confirming just in case that anyone cares, as it's already 3 years since the first comment)

Comment: I updated to cmake v3.7, and this did not work for me. In fact, I also tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029277/how-to-modify-environment-variables-passed-to-custom-cmake-target
I tested it by doing
cmake -E env ENV{PATH}=${PATH}:~/source/new/path/to/add export PATH=${PATH}:~/source/new/path/to/add which returned "No such file or directory"

Comment: It seems that what some of you wanted is `cmake -E env`, which makes set variable available to child process: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64823115/714907.

Comment: Took me a long time to see you need to put a D before the variable name. Then' the name is without the D.

Answer (score 7):

The only way to set a compiler and flags to do cross-compilation reliably with CMake is with a toolchain-file as done in the tutorial you have found.

When we faced the same issue you have (a toolkit which produces a script so set the compile-environment) we changed the toolkit in a way that it produces a toolchain-file along with the script.

In reality a cmake-toolchain-file does not change that often. The basic flags used for the target are fixed quite early in a project - normally. And with CMake's `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` you can switch between Debug and Release compilations without changing the toolchain-file.

If you have different targets to support, create different toolchain and use the out-of-source-build with CMake.

*EDIT*: One thing you could do is to invoke cmake with the -D-argument setting the variables you want to and having sourced your script before:

```
source environment-setup-powerpc-linux
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$CC -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$CXX etc
```

The result will be identical as to having used a toolchain-file.

Comment: so, does it mean there are no ways to do what I wanted? Although it doesn't change often, it does change. Then someone has to not forget to convert that script into cmake rules.

Comment: In the current way cmake is doing things you cannot simply tell cmake to import a script like you have it. Of course you can create a wrapper-script which transforms you script into a toolchain-file, but this is still work you have to do.