# Edit custom path with OpenCV framework using CMake to generate XCODE project in iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, cmake, cross-platform

I have a cross-platform build system using CMake, and I have OpenCV dependency for iOS.

Setting `${OpenCV_DIR}` manually, my project compile and execute correctly if and only if I set manually every time I generate XCODE project variable `Project > Build Settings > Framework Search Paths` with `${OpenCV_DIR}`.

How can I set this variable using CMake directly?

Comment: Not sure I get your question right: do you want to specify OpenCV_DIR when runnin CMake? In which ase run cmake with `-DOpenCV_DIR=/path/to/opencv`. Or do you want that CMake sets up the environment variable OpenCV_DIR? in which case [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21202129/1652461)

Comment: XCode use a serie of variables in the projects. But it seems like lot of them are not filled by CMake. CMake set some info maps that mekae excode copile using info un build folder, but frarmework search path never is detected to me. I want to fill that path, or find the way to be found when XCode compiles.

Comment: Have you read this documentation http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation ?

Comment: I'm not building OpenCV. I'm using OpenCV in a cross-platform project. It works perfectly for Windows, Linux and Android, but I cannot link automatically prebuilt framework in iOS/MAC

Comment: iOS/MAC is very similar to linux isn't it? Cant you just modify OpenCV CMakeLists to export the environment variable that you need as in the link in my first comment?

Comment: Ios/MAC & Linux are based in UNIX, thats all. I need to edit, if is possible, XCode variables. If not, I need a way to compile using OpenCV_DIR with framework, but without edit enviroment variables. I always use local variables, if need edit manually, but inside CMake project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake has no full integration with XCode. You can generate a project using it but a lot of things fails. Just drag into your project `OpenCV` and it will be detected.

Comment: Just to clarify, to make the magic: 1º Drag the framework, 2º add the path containing the framework to Search framework path in the Build settings of the target and it will work