# How to modify environment variables passed to custom CMake target?

Tags: cmake, environment-variables

Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure out how to explicitly set environment variables that can be seen by processes launched through [`add_custom_target()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html).

I tried the following:

```
set(ENV{PATH} "C:/Some/Path;$ENV{PATH}")
add_custom_target(newtarget somecommand)
```

Unfortunately, the `%PATH%` environment variable appears unchanged to `somecommand`. (I have set up a Gist that reproduces the problem [here](https://gist.github.com/nathan-osman/785152e6452559852fc8).)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest that since you are creating a new process (from your comments) then the new process will be provided its own environemt, not inherit the environment of the main process. If you create a child process of the main process, then the environment should be inherited - but I know nothing of `cmake` so I may be way off here. You should however use `backslash` as directory-separators, not `/` as `/` is a switch-prefix. Sometimes `/` works happily, but it's not reliable.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

A portable way of setting environment variables for a custom target is to use CMake's command-line tool mode command `env`:

> ```
> env [--unset=NAME]... [NAME=VALUE]... COMMAND [ARG]...
> ```
>
> Run command in a modified environment.

E.g.:

```
add_custom_target(newtarget ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env NAME=VALUE somecommand)
```

Also see [Command Line Tool Mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool).

Comment: Does that add an implicit dependency to "somecommand" if it is the name of a target? Which is done if "somecommand" appears as first position

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I don't think so. Use the `DEPENDS` option or `add_dependencies` to make the dependency explicit.

Comment: I figured that you can use `$<TARGET_FILE:somecommand>` if it is a target. This will also automatically add a dependency, and resolves the target name to the path of the binary.

Answer (score 28):

You set environment variable at *configuration* step, but command specified for `add_custom_target` is executed at *build* step. See also CMake FAQ: [How can I get or set environment variables?](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-get-or-set-environment-variables)

> [...]
>   environment variables `SET` in the CMakeLists.txt *only*
>   take effect for cmake itself (*configure-time*),
>   so you cannot use this method to set an environment variable
>   that a custom command might need (*build-time*). 
>   Barring environment variable support by various CMake commands
>   (e.g. `add_custom_command()`, currently not supported yet),
>   an acceptable workaround may be to invoke shell scripts instead
>   which wrap the commands to be executed.

Currently `add_custom_target` (and others commands, which define actions for build step, e.g. `add_custom_command`) doesn't support simple setting environment variables. As adviced in [this bugreport](https://cmake.org/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=5145), for set variable's value *without spaces* on Linux you may prepend command with "VAR=VAL" clauses. For general cases you may prepare *wrapper* script, which setups environment and run actual command:

On Windows:

**wrapper.bat**:

```
@ECHO OFF
set PATH=C:\\Some\\Path;%PATH%
%*
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_custom_target(...
    COMMAND cmd /c ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wrapper.bat <real_command> args...
)
```

On Linux:

**wrapper.sh**:

```
export "PATH=/Some/Path:$PATH"
eval "$*"
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_custom_target(...
    COMMAND /bin/sh ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wrapper.sh <real_command> args...
)
```

If value of variable depends on configuration, you may configure wrapper script with `configure_file`.

**UPDATE**:

As noted by @sakra, `env` tool mode of `cmake` executable can be used as a wrapper script:

```
add_custom_target(...
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env "PATH=C:/Some/Path;$ENV{PATH}" <real_command> args...
)
```

This way is available since CMake 3.2.

Comment: what to write instead 3 dots ? What the "real_command"? What the "args"?
Poor answer

Comment: The first argument for `add_custom_target()` is the target name. `<real_command>` is a replacement for original `COMMAND` parameter and `args...` is the original command's arguments.

Comment: Without full example i'm totally not understand how this command work, sorry

Comment: If you don't understand what `add_custom_target` does, you may look into [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_custom_target.html) or ask a new question on Stack Overflow. Current question post contains invocation `add_custom_target(newtarget somecommand)`, so both answers (sakra's one and my) implies that meaning of this invocation is known to the readers.

Comment: Cmake documentation without example - i still don't understand after spend many time! So, this answers not help me.

Comment: Вы вроде русский, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/939302/clion-%d0%b8-cmake%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: partially related

Comment: The quotes in wrapper.bat caused me problems. The resulting PATH variable value included the quotes which caused the first and last directories to not work correctly. Removing the quotes fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I had wrote the script without checking it. Now the answer is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer to this, but perhaps it will help somebody.  We use the && operator to do this in our cmake files on Windows.

```
set(MY_COMMAND set "PATH=C:\\some\\path\;%PATH%"&&
        somecommand)

add_custom_target(TARGET newtarget COMMAND ${MY_COMMAND})
```

Note that you cannot have a space before the && (for reasons I don't understand completely).  Also, spaces are a real pain to deal with here, so I don't know if I have it right if c:\some\path has spaces.  It does work if your original path has spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The command works for me

```
add_custom_target(
    run
    DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    COMMAND ASAN_OPTIONS=alloc_dealloc_mismatch=0 ./${PROJECT_NAME}
)
```