# CMake quote escape conumdrum

Tags: cmake, escaping, double-quotes

I just don't seem to be able to wrap my head around CMake's escape rules. Given:

```
set(X A B C)
add_custom_target( works COMMAND DUMMY=0 X="${X}" env | grep ^X= COMMENT "This works")
add_custom_target( fails COMMAND X="${X}" env | grep ^X= COMMENT "This fails")
```

The intention is to execute command `X="A B C" env`. The custom target `works` correctly constructs the command, where as `fails` incorrectly executes:

```
X=\"A B C\" env ...
```

But why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake: when to quote variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables) Do try `set(X "A B C")` and don't put quotes around the `${X}`.

Comment: @Florian, `set(X "A B C")` results in: `"X=\"A B C\"" env`, which is still wrong.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, `ExternalProject_Add_Step(COMMAND build --args="my args")` will execute `build --args=\"my args\"` which is incorrect. I'll start a bounty if I can't find a solution tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you ran into two problems:

1. Don't quote CMake variables in custom commands. CMake will do the necessary escape sequences for you.
2. The first literal after `COMMAND` is assumed to be a command name or file. So CMake tries to handle it as a single "string".

So I changed the quoting and the `env` call and the following did work for me:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(QuotedStrings)

set(X "A B C")
add_custom_target( works COMMAND env DUMMY=0 X=${X} | grep ^X= COMMENT "This works")
add_custom_target( fails_no_more COMMAND env X=${X} | grep ^X= COMMENT "This works too")
```

For more details and possibilities see:

- [cmake: How to include literal double-quote in custom command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368525/cmake-how-to-include-literal-double-quote-in-custom-command)
- [cmake: when to quote variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables)