# CMake: unescape whitespace when echoing to a file

Tags: cmake

As part of our build process we automatically run unit tests through valgrind during the actual build (ie: it's not a separate target such as `make test`)

We create a sentinel file when the tests pass, so that subsequent build won't rerun the tests if not necessary.

We also save the command line and test output to a file.

Here I have built the valgrind command line:

```
set(VALGRIND_BIN  "valgrind")
set(VALGRIND_OPTS "--leak-check=full --track-origins=yes")

set(VALGRIND_CMD "${VALGRIND_BIN} ${VALGRIND_OPTS}")
separate_arguments(VALGRIND_CMD)
```

These are the "passed" sentinal file, and the test output file.

```
set(OUTPUT_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${ARG_NAME}.output)
set(PASSED_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${ARG_NAME}.passed)
```

Here I add a `custom_command` which works in the following way:

- It echos the command line and saves it to the output file
- It runs the test through valgrind, saving all output to the output file
- If the test doesn't pass it will cat the output file and the command fails
- If the test passes it will touch the passed sentinel file.

Here is the cmake source:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${PASSED_FILE}

    COMMAND
        echo "\"${VALGRIND_BIN} ${VALGRIND_OPTS} $<TARGET_FILE:${TEST_NAME}>\"" > ${OUTPUT_FILE}

    COMMAND
        ${VALGRIND_CMD} $<TARGET_FILE:${TEST_NAME}> >> ${OUTPUT_FILE} 2>&1 || (cat ${OUTPUT_FILE} && false)

    COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${PASSED_FILE}

    COMMENT
        "Running ${ARG_NAME} tests"

    DEPENDS
        ${TEST_NAME}

    USES_TERMINAL
    )
```

Unfortunately cmake is escaping all the whitespace in my `echo` of the test command line, so that the first line in the output file looks like this:

```
valgrind\ --leak-check=full\ --track-origins=yes\ /home/steve/src/test\
```

I have proven to myself the escapes aren't in the variables, as if I output a `message` they aren't in there.

```
message(STATUS "\"${VALGRIND_BIN} ${VALGRIND_OPTS} $<TARGET_FILE:${TEST_NAME}>\"")
```

The resulting output:

```
-- "valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes $<TARGET_FILE:test>"
```

**Question:**

How can I *unescape* the whitespace when echoing to a file?

That is, how can I have the line not be this:

```
valgrind\ --leak-check=full\ --track-origins=yes\ /home/steve/src/test\
```

but instead be this:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes /home/steve/src/test
```

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/add_custom_command.html - maybe the "VERBATIM" flag would work for you?

Comment: @MuertoExcobito whilst this works for the `echo`, it breaks the 2nd part of the test command (the call to `|| (cat ${OUTPUT_FILE} && false)`) as it surrounds the parens with quotes `"("`, resulting in `|| "(" cat OUTPUT_FILE && false ")"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put everything into a list, which will be expanded and the spaces will not be escaped.

Because CMake will be escaping spaces if it believes the string to be a single argument. Giving it as a list will take every element as a separate argument:

```perl
list(APPEND VALGRIND_CMD "$<TARGET_FILE:${TEST_NAME}>")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${PASSED_FILE}
    COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo \"${VALGRIND_CMD}\" > ${OUTPUT_FILE}
    COMMAND
        ${VALGRIND_CMD} >> ${OUTPUT_FILE} 2>&1 || (cat ${OUTPUT_FILE} && false)
    COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${PASSED_FILE}
    COMMENT
        "Running ${ARG_NAME} tests"
    USES_TERMINAL
)
```

**References**

- [cmake: How to include literal double-quote in custom command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368525/cmake-how-to-include-literal-double-quote-in-custom-command)
- [cmake: when to quote variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @MuertoExcobito, option *VERBATIM* cares about properly escaping parameters, no needs in additional double quotes escaped manually:

```
COMMAND
    echo "${VALGRIND_BIN} ${VALGRIND_OPTS} $<TARGET_FILE:${TEST_NAME}>" > ${OUTPUT_FILE}
VERBATIM
```

(Outer double quotes are needed for CMake do not separate echo parameters).

Comment: Whilst this works for the `echo`, it breaks the 2nd part of the test command (the call to `|| (cat ${OUTPUT_FILE} && false)`) as it surrounds the parens with quotes `"("`, resulting in `|| "(" cat OUTPUT_FILE && false ")"`

Comment: So the question should be titled "How to unescape whitespaces without VERBATIM" :D.Well, as for this specific case, why do you ever need to separate arguments for `echo` (outer double quotes)? When output, this command automatically delimits its argument with spaces.