# cmake -E equivalent in cmake 2.8

Tags: cmake

I am new to cmake and i am working with a 3.1 CMakefile with -E env option and I am backporting it to 2.8. What is the compatible or equivalent option in 2.8?

https://github.com/CZ-NIC/turris-os/blob/master/package/system/ubus/patches/001-python.patch

The line I am dealing with is

```
+ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(python ALL
+ COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env "CC=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}
${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ARG1}" "LDSHARED=${LDSHARED}" "CFLAGS=${PYTHON_CFLAGS}"
${PYTHON} ${SETUP_PY} build
+ DEPENDS ubus "${CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ubus_python.c"
+)
+
+INSTALL(
+ CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env \"CC=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ARG1}\" \"LDSHARED=${LDSHARED}\" \"CFLAGS=${PYTHON_CFLAGS}\" ${PYTHON} ${SETUP_PY} install --    prefix=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})"
+)
```

-Zer0_0ne

Comment: Related (or even duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029277/how-to-modify-environment-variables-passed-to-custom-cmake-target.