# How to specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH via add_custom_command?

Tags: linux, cmake

I am trying to add ld_library_path via cmake.

What I have done so far is

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${target}
   POST_BUILD
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:${target}> ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin
   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
   COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:${target}>
   ################ ENV Set here ####################
   -E env "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/boost_linux/lib"

   COMMENT "Running Tests Now .. " VERBATIM
)
```

But I am still getting linking error during runtime. Does any one know how to properly link lib path.

In bash it would be like
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/path/to/lib`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify environment variables passed to custom CMake target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029277/how-to-modify-environment-variables-passed-to-custom-cmake-target)

Comment: For `add_custom_command` environment variable is set in the same way as for `add_custom_target`. Note, that `${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` in your code refers to **CMake variable**, not to the environment one. For refer to environment variable, use `$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`.

Comment: ENVIRONMENT LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/path/to/lib and still does not work.

Comment: There is no `ENVIRONMENT` option for `add_custom_command`, you may check that in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html). Just use answers from the referenced question.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I did `COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:${target}> -E env "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/lib"` .. I print before after the message("----------Env-----> $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}") but get the same LD_LIBRARY_PATH value

Comment: You incorrectly interpret [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35042808/3440745): You need `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/lib" $<TARGET_FILE:${target}>`. Also note, that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will be changed only during the command execution, at **build** stage. You cannot observe this changing with `message()` command in `CMakeLists.txt`, which is executed at **configuration** stage.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve and how it is related to a linking error. But the way you run commands with custom environment variables is the following:

```
add_custom_command(
  ...
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=..."
    actual command line that you need to execute
)
```

So, `-E env` works such that it executes whatever is passed after env variable specification.

Note, however, that you cannot use multiple `COMMAND` arguments and set env in the first one while using it in the following `COMMAND`s - it won't work. Or, at least, it is generator-dependent. With Make backend this is translated into multiple calls to shell - so it sets the env but the rest of commands are executed separately and don't see it. Ninja generator translates multiple `COMMAND`s into something like `cmd1 && cmd2 && ...` so it works there, AFAIK.

Comment: I am actually trying to run uni test executable after  it is being created and ` COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:${target}>` command does that for me. I do this so that cmake runs my unit test executable during the cmake build.

Comment: Well, this is unrelated to the topic of custom commands, but I recommend using `add_test` for testing instead. Running tests during the build might be very inconvenient. First, it takes extra time to finish the build, while one might want to see it running asap. Second, a failure in one small flacky test will stop the whole build, even though it's otherwise fully functional.