# How to set the PATH environment variable for CMAKE ExternalProject_Add_Step?

Tags: cmake

I'm adding Google's native webrtc library as an external dependency to a CMake project I'm working on. The build process for the webrtc library is rather convoluted but the initial steps are as follows:

1. Cloning chromium depot_tools repo
2. Adding depot_tools to environment PATH
3. Running `fetch --nohooks webrtc` (`fetch` tool is found in PATH from previous step)
4. Several further steps I'll omit as they're not relevant to the question

I can successfully perform all these steps manually from the command line to build the library.

To simply my build process I thought I'd use `ExternalProject_Add` with several `ExternalProject_Add_Step`s to create a target that my main project can use as a dependency:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
        ${PROJECT_NAME} 
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND "" 
        UPDATE_COMMAND "" 
        PATCH_COMMAND "" 
        BUILD_COMMAND "" 
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_Add_Step(
        ${PROJECT_NAME} fetch-webrtc
        COMMAND fetch --nohooks webrtc # <--- how to get fetch into PATH?
        DEPENDEES mkdir-webrtc
)

...
```

The problem I have is that when the `fetch-webrtc` step is run the `fetch` tool is not in the PATH. Now I could "cheat" and change the above step to the following:

```
ExternalProject_Get_Property(${PROJECT_NAME} SOURCE_DIR)
ExternalProject_Add_Step(
        ${PROJECT_NAME} fetch-webrtc
        COMMAND ${SOURCE_DIR}/fetch --nohooks webrtc # fetch is found!
        DEPENDEES mkdir-webrtc
)
```

This partly solves the issue, however the `fetch` command itself requires the depot_tools repo to be in the path as it looks for many files there - thus things ultimately fail.

So how can I go about getting the depot_tools directory into the PATH environment variable (ideally *prefixed to the front* of all the PATH directories) available for all `ExternalProject_Add_Step` steps?

Comment: COMMAND clause in `ExternalProject_Add_Step` denotes the same as COMMAND 
clause in the `add_custom_command`/`add_custom_target`. So the answers from [the question about custom target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029277/how-to-modify-environment-variables-passed-to-custom-cmake-target) are applicable for your case too.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev . I had actually tried the selected answer in that post, which for whatever reason did not work for me so I dismissed it. Your `wrapper.bat` / `wrapper.sh` approach did though!