# How to set OpenCv Environment Variable and Path Variable on a Mac?

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am doing a [tutorial](https://github.com/keplerlab/neuralCreativityServer/tree/master/server) on how to install and use Opencv with Cmake. I have gotten through to a step that says `Set OpenCV_DIR environment variable to path to Opencv install folder` and the directly after `Set Path variable where Opencv is installed`. I am lost and all the tutorials / solutions I have looked at seem outdated or do not work. Please could someone show me how to do this. Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows, the quick way is to open CMake GUI application and change the variable wherever you want. For a Mac/Linux machine, command line might be your best choice, and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047399/cmake-set-environment-variables-from-a-script) will be really helpful for you.