# Executing a script to set environment variables before CMake configuration in CLion

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, clion, toolchain

I'm setting up a cross-compiling environment with CLion and need to execute a specific configuration script *before* configuring CMake.

I can do it in the command line as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21074163/1485885):

```sh
source /path/to/the-script
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$CC -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$CXX ...
```

Also, I can do it in VS Code through the CMake kits (`.vscode/cmake-kits.json`):

```json
[
    {
        "name": "ARM",
        "environmentSetupScript": "/path/to/the-script"
    }
]
```

Now I'd like to do the same in CLion but all that I can do is

1. Define all the environment variables manually using `-D`.
2. Use a CMake toolchain file through `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`, but I don't have a .cmake file but a script. The script may change every time the toolchain is updated, so I'd like to avoid preparing one manually.

So, is there any way to execute the script *before* launching CMake in CLion?

Comment: `but I don't have a .cmake file but a script. The script may change every time the toolchain is updated` so run the script from the toolchain file??

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to source a script. So instead, I run `printenv` before and after running the source script and then I stored all new/modified env variables in CLion cmake configuration (field *Environment*).

Answer (score 1):

This might be [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If your script just sets a bunch of environment variables, you can create a CMakePresets.json file and define a configuration preset that sets those environment variables.

- The official CMake documentation for CMakePresets files is [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html).
- The CLion user guide on CMakePresets files is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-presets.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:
In Clion click on Run -> Edit Configurations

Click on + and add Makefile Target. Select the path for the Makefile that will be generated.

Then go to Before Launch and click on + -> Run External Tool.
Here click another time on + and add the script you want to execute.

Then you can build and compile your project clicking on the Run arrow.